# Aggregate data in a SSAS hierarchy

Tags: ssas, mdx, hierarchy, hierarchical-data

I have a hierarchy in a dimension in my cube, and a fact table that references that dimension. Let's call that a hierarchy of departments and the fact table contains billing targets set for each department (on a record-per-day basis if that's of any interest).
The data is aggregated as in a usual hierarchy in a multidimensional cube.

The problem is that the data in the fact table is not just limited to the "leaf" departments in the hierarchy tree, and so each node/department may or may not have an actual value for a billing target.

I need to have my measure returning the actual value for any node if there is a value, or the sum of the values of it's descendants (if they themselves have actual values, then ignore their descendants).
I can return the value at any given node by using the `.DATAMEMBER` property and add a condition to substitute the null (if that is the case) with the sum of descendants as so:

`with member DirectD as (iif(([Department].[Departments].currentmember.datamember, [Measures].[Department Billing Target]) = null, 
([Measures].[Department Billing Target]), 
([Department].[Departments].currentmember.datamember, [Measures].[Department Billing Target])))`

The problem is that I cannot ensure that the same logic applies to every node "down" the hierarchy.
The `MembersWithData` setting is set to `NonLeafDataHidden` in the dimension.
`[Measures].[Department Billing Target]` is a calculated member, so it looks like `Aggregate` is not an option.

As an example, I'd like to get the value of 3000 if I query the billing target for department A (image 1):
[image: Image 1]

For department C on Image 2 I need to get 1400 (E, while having descendants, has an actual value which takes precedence over the sum of it's children).
[image: Image 2]

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The Hierarchy that you mention seems to be a parentchild hierarchy since you say "The problem is that the data in the fact table is not just limited to the "leaf" departments in the hierarchy tree". Based on this, the problem is that we need to solve is 
1)Foreach member of you hierarchy we call the base attribute.
2)If the measure value for the base attribute is null we retuen the summed up value
3)If the measure value for the base attribute is not null then we retuen the indivisual members value. Below is the code piece, there can be some syntax issues but would explain the idea.

The below code is a similar example on adventure works(I did add FullName attribute in the employee dimension). In the picture on right is a parent child hierarchy's, base attribute. This picture show all the employee who had sales. On the left is the hierarchy, notice how the values change in the Test measure for people who are present on the right hand side. For example take a look at "Amy E. Alberts"

[image]

The code is

```
with member [Measures].test as
case when [Employee].[Employees].currentmember.name='All Employees' 
then [Measures].[Reseller Sales Amount]
when (strtomember('[Employee].[Full Name].['+[Employee].[Employees].currentmember.name+']'),[Measures].[Reseller Sales Amount])=null 
then [Measures].[Reseller Sales Amount]
else (strtomember('[Employee].[Full Name].['+[Employee].[Employees].currentmember.name+']'),[Measures].[Reseller Sales Amount])
end
select {[Measures].[Reseller Sales Amount],[Measures].test}
on columns,
[Employee].[Employees].members 
on rows from [Adventure Works]
```

Comment: You're right about the problem that I'm having.I have a couple of questions:

a) Why use the big expression with `linkmember` when returning the individual value when `....currentmember.datamember` does the same? (perhaps it does not and I'm just not aware of some adavantage of `linkmember`).

b) The member explicitly lists levels. I cannot know how many levels will there be, so I'm thinking it's not a "generic" enough solution.

Comment: Having read a bit about `linkmember` (haven't used  it before) I cannot understand how it is useful here since both the "left" and "right" hierarchies/dimensions are the same.

Comment: @Shvets it should not matter if your dimension is same. Your problem is you need to use Departments own value if it has one, else use the sum of its children. For this at each level, for each member you need to fetch the members own value. To get members own value you need to check for that member without the hierarchy and within its base attribute. This is where link members comes in.

Comment: @Shvets does the edited query work? I hope it is of help.

Comment: I could not test it unfortunately as I get some other error in the query ("Internal error: An unexpected exception occurred.") - unrelated, but still stalling me.

Comment: @Shvets you got error on adventureworks sample that i pasted above or your own query?

Comment: @Shvets any luck with this?

Comment: I have tried the code above, but it makes no difference it terms of results. It works if I have a hierarchy of only two levels and if I add `.DATAMEMBER` to the StrTomember in the last else clause. I am also not quite sure about the use of `StrToMember` if `[Employee].[Full Name].currentmember` would suffice.

Comment: I have been distracted by other tasks, but all the options I have tried so far failed to achieve that tree traversing that I need.

Comment: @Shvets the above query was tested for a parent child hierarchy containing six levels.

Comment: I imported AdventureWorkds cube locally and just could not reproduce your results. For me the "test" member was always the same as the regular "Reseller Sales Amount".

Comment: @Shvets, you could not reproduce the results because you probably missed the step memtioned in the first line of second para "The below code is a similar example on adventure works(I did add FullName attribute in the employee dimension)". In the imported adventure works Cube open the project and in Employees dimension add the FullName as attribute. The Employee parent child hierarchy is based on this Full Name. You might require the AdventureworksDW for this. https://github.com/Microsoft/sql-server-samples/releases/download/adventureworks/AdventureWorksDW-data-warehouse-install-script.zip

Comment: @Shvets the Idea in the above solution is to use the underlying attribute Hierarchy of the Paraent Child Hierarchy

Comment: @Shvets any luck with the relevant changes with AdventureWorks

Answer (score 0):

In the end, I have added the following solution that is working so far:

```
    IIF(NOT ISEMPTY(([Department].[Departments].CURRENTMEMBER.DATABEMBER, [Measures].[Department Billing Target Canonical])), 
  ([Department].[Departments].CURRENTMEMBER.DATABEMBER, [Measures].[Department Billing Target Canonical]), 
  IIF(ISEMPTY(SUM(descendants([Department].[Departments].CURRENTMEMBER, [Department].[Departments], AFTER), IIF(
    ISEMPTY(([Department].[Departments].CURRENTMEMBER.parent.DATABEMBER, [Measures].[Department Billing Target Canonical])), 
    ([Department].[Departments].CURRENTMEMBER.DATABEMBER, [Measures].[Department Billing Target Canonical]), 
    NULL))), 
  ([Department].[Departments].CURRENTMEMBER.DATABEMBER, [Measures].[Department Billing Target Canonical]), 
  SUM(descendants([Department].[Departments].CURRENTMEMBER, [Department].[Departments], AFTER), IIF(
    ISEMPTY(([Department].[Departments].CURRENTMEMBER.parent.DATABEMBER, [Measures].[Department Billing Target Canonical])), 
    ([Department].[Departments].CURRENTMEMBER.DATABEMBER, [Measures].[Department Billing Target Canonical]), 
    NULL))))
```

Granted it may not be the prettiest solution (in fact I'm pretty sure it's one of the ugliest), but it works for me.

The gist of it is that the algorithm checks if the parent node of the current one has any data (currentmember.parent.datamember) and if so, substitutes the current member's value with NULL. All those values are piled up in a set, and the sum of it's "contents" is the resulting value. The outmost IIF is there to cover a sort of an edge case.

EDIT: There is also a feeling that this whole issue is just a matter of some SSAS setting that has to be changed. This setting continues to elude me.